# ArcPy module not found in PyCharm?

Tags: arcpy, installation, pycharm

I have installed PyCharm Edu and am trying to run a python script calling on ArcPy.

I get an import arcpy module error:

[image]

However, when I use the python scripter in ArcGIS Desktop, I see that it is able to find arcpy

[image]

I tried finding the actual arcpy folder in C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\Lib, but am unable to find it.

Why do I get the arcpy module error on Pycharm?

Is there an installation error in ArcGIS Desktop or PyCharm?

Comment: You possibly need to reinstall arcpy if it was installed before you installed Pycharm

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up PyCharm's Interpreter like this:

C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\python.exe

Comment: That path doesnt exist. Only C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib exists. Is that the problem?

Comment: my installation is in version 10.6, i don't know if there's difference, but, check where is the path of 'exe' from python.